# Spring/Hibernate project @Transactional annotation value is not used and substituted automatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I have a problem with spring 4/hibernate 4 and xml database configuration in the project.
Database is divided into 2. Wrong transactionManager specified at `@Transactional`, yet hibernate connects to a correct database without throwing any exceptions.
Dao methods are annotated with `@Transactional` like following:

```
@Repository
public class SampleDao {

    @Transactional("database2TransactionManager")
    public SamplePojo getSamplePojo(String smth) {
    database1SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(SamplePojo.class)
        //some code
    }
}
```

Let’s say that `SampleDao.getSamplePojo()` actually gets data from database1 defined with database1TransactionManager. In this case `@Transactional` value is ignored and database1TransactionManager is used instead.

See
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional

Is it possible to have the query being restricted on using `@Transactional` specified transactionManager rather than any other even if it throws an exception. Even when `@Transactional` specifies name with typo as transactionManager.

database.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="database1TransactionManager"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="database2TransactionManager"/>

<!--  Database related configuration  -->
<bean id="database1DataSource" destroy-method="close">
//properties
</bean>

<!--  Database related configuration  -->
<bean id="database2DataSource" destroy-method="close">
//properties
</bean>

<bean id="database1SessionFactory" name="database1SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" depends-on="database1DataSource">
//properties
</bean>

<bean id="database2SessionFactory" name="database2SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" depends-on="database2DataSource">
//properties
</bean>

<bean id="database1TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" depends-on="database1SessionFactory">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="database1SessionFactory"/>
    <qualifier value="database1TransactionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="database2TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" depends-on="database2SessionFactory">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="database2SessionFactory"/>
    <qualifier value="database2TransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

I use separate databases so it is important that such mistakes get shown and I am aware of them rather than Spring 4 does some substitutions automatically.
I did some debugging and that is what I have found. There is a DAO method marked with @Transactional, database2TransactionManager specified for it. However, database2TransactionManager cannot anyhow be used in this method as it is accessed through database1SessionFactory. These are 2 separate databases with separate users etc. So actually, Spring does not use database2TransactionManager, it gets substituted with values from database1SessionFactory. So it came out that there was wrong @Transactional config, which still worked by spring interactions.

Comment: For starters remove one of the `<tx:annotation-driven />` elements only one is effective anyway. However what you want isn't possible you either have a single default transaction manager or need to specify explicitly which one to use. Do you really need 2 session factories and 2 transaction managers or do you only think you need them?

Comment: @M.Deinum Can't we have multiple transaction managers ? He has separate qualifiers. Refer : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional

Comment: Yes you can but you can have only 1 `<tx:annotation-driven />`. That is only for enabling `@Transactional` and telling that which tx- manger to use by default. In this case the last one wins and `database2TransactionManager` will be the default (i.e. for `@Transactional` with no specific one specified this one will be used). The number of transaction managers doesn't influence the number of `<tx:annotation-driven />` elements. Having more then one simply doesn't make sense...

Comment: I did some debugging and that is what I have found. There is a DAO method marked with @Transactional, database2TransactionManager specified for it. However, database2TransactionManager cannot anyhow be used in this method as it is accessed through database1SessionFactory

Comment: Please be aware that what you put in `@Transactional` does not need to correspond what is actually used. `@Transactional` simply starts transaction and binds it with the current thread.

Comment: Pavel, but how does then Spring knows, which transaction manager to use? Does it tries to infer from the session factory what is being used?

You can clearly see in example, that there are two separate machines with separate databases/schemes, a method is marked to use database1TransactionManager ( which is connected to database1 data source ), but hibernate session factory is used for database 2.

So do we have two transactions here? one for database1 and it starts when method is called, and one for database2 and it starts when session factory for database 2 is used?

Comment: I see, @Transactional value is optional. Meaning it is even redundant or it serves some purpose. Because when the value is occasionally incorrect, then it is strange and even frightening.

Comment: As whatever the value is, transactions still work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. It was decided that I do not really need any Spring Transaction Synchronisation.
I added this to database.xml:

property name="transactionSynchronization" value="2"

Now the exception was thrown in case of incorrect @Transactional value.